# Object in Cycles is getting illuminated but stays black in Eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, eevee-render-engine

I am working on a space scene using a 3D model of a starbase that I downloaded online. There's a sun in the scene that illuminates the starbase. The starbase gets illuminated in Cycles, but when I switch to Eevee, it does not receive any light from the sun.

[image: Comparison]

The node tree of one of the "head" of the mushroom-shaped starbase looks like this: 
[image: Node tree]

Am I missing something fundamental that you more seasoned pretzels can see at the first glance?

Comment: Have you tried to bake indirect light? Maybe placing a reflection cubemap around the spaceship?

Comment: it should work, as the directional light is no material emission or primarily indirect. Maby its something else? Could you upload a file?

Comment: Sure - here it is: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohDmDW98tXLg91V8xNw6WMVLYj1Ng?e=I4ZhUl Many thanks!

Comment: @AM, did you have a chance to take a look?

Comment: sry tried to take a look, but the file is pretty complicated (many small nested parts) and i dont have much time at the moment. What i found was that there are countless lamps inside the station. Also copying the hole station to a fresh blend-file brings the error along, copying single elements doesnt. Maby this way you could narrow it down, which object causes this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could narrow it down to the huge number of lights (134) in the scene.
Deleting all lights and adding a fresh sun restores the display of shadows. By using the new filtering parameters, lights can easily be found:

It looks like that eevee cant handle that many lights and additional ones will simply be ignored:  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html

[image]

[image: unfortunately]

Comment: Very interesting. Not what I expected, but it seems to be the right answer. Thank you!